# What does もえと mean?

Tags: parsing, particle-も

I was reading a Tofugu article, https://www.tofugu.com/japanese/da-vs-desu-in-real-life/, and one of the examples they give was this text conversation.

I'm just curious what 私｛わたし｝ももえと could mean. My best guess is that もえ is a name, so the person's saying "I want to talk with you (Moe) too!"

I also found that ももえ is a name, but I don't think that's what's being said in this case.

I know there's not really any context to go off but, how should I interpret 「私｛わたし｝ももえと電話｛でんわ｝したい！」 If もえ is a name, is it common??

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to [明治安田生命{めいじやすだせいめい} : 名前ランキング](https://www.meijiyasuda.co.jp/sp/enjoy/ranking/index.html#/detail/n_33804), the name 「萌{もえ}」 is in the top 10 is given to girls in Japan for 1 decade from 1993 to 2013.

The kanji : 「萌」 is the most common for the phonetic name : 「もえ」, so 「もえ」is also very common girl's name.

---

Curiously, 「百恵｛ももえ} 」from [「山口｛やまぐち}百恵｛ももえ}」](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E5%B1%B1%E5%8F%A3%E7%99%BE%E6%81%B5), who is one of the most famous female singer in Japan during 70's to 80's, does not appear in the ranking (They've made the ranking for nearly one century from 1912) since I suppose people tend to give name to be nice like a popular person (大輔{だいすけ} from [荒木{あらき} 大輔{だいすけ}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E8%8D%92%E6%9C%A8%E5%A4%A7%E8%BC%94) : Japanese baseball player was popular in highschool baseball tournament , 翼{つばさ} : the protagonist from [キャプテン翼{つばさ}](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%82%AD%E3%83%A3%E3%83%97%E3%83%86%E3%83%B3%E7%BF%BC) are the ones).

Answer (score 6):

I believe that the name is highly likely to be もえ instead of ももえ. While both names exist, the context makes it clear: the sender (the green balloon) asked first whether they can have the phone call and the replier (the white balloon) is replying 私ももえと電話したい. If it were to be interpreted as 私、ももえと電話したい, it will sound abrupt and out of context, since 私、ももえと電話したい would imply that the white balloon is starting the topic of having a phone call between them. In reality, the white balloon is replying to the context created by the green balloon and is telling that he/she (likely she) wants to have a phone call, **too**. Thus, 私ももえと電話したい should be interpreted as "I want to have a phone call with you (Moe), too", not as "I want to have a phone call with you (Momoe)".

Answer (score -1):

The name is likely ももえ, with an omitted は after 私.